# Where to handle DataGridView format errors

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to find out where to handle the error I keep getting when I type in a date into the date cell, by incorrectly using `;` instead of `:`.

The application is in C# using Visual Studio 2017.

[screenshot of dataGridView formatting error message:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdb5g.png)

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Thanks
Simon

Comment: Sorry and Thanks.

Comment: Still, without seeing code, it's impossible to tell you where in your code you should do something. Plus: Error messages / stack traces should be in the question, not in an image.

Comment: Still have to ask: **did** you read the very last line in the dialog shown in your picture?

Comment: @FelixPalmen Seems to be the conclusion this person arrived at too: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b37237e4-73da-4f08-b497-edb4ab044afd/where-to-catch-an-formatexception?forum=winformsdatacontrols

Comment: Yes you where right, I managed to sort my problem out, just needed pointing in the right direction.

Comment: To meet StackOverflow guidelines, please post relevant code to question.  In addition to helping us help you, it keeps the question understandable and relevant for future visitors which may have similar issues.  Please `edit` accordingly.  Thank you, and glad you found your answer.  Also, note that you can post the solution you came up with (if another person hasn't posted essentially the same thing) as an **Answer**, and even *accept* it as the one that solved your issue.  Again, this will help future visitors, (and earn you some SO points).

Comment: Also, Please do NOT post image links in the Question *Title*! SO is not designed to be used that way, and the majority of people will Not see it. I instead, embed necessary images in the **body* of the question. Finally, Error Messages, and Code should by Posted as Text within the body of the question. 
 This enables users to copy/paste code and error messages (into editors, search engines, etc) which they may need to do to help them solve your problem.  It can also be difficult to *read* screenshots of text!  Please review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to take a look at the stack trace of your error. You will see a Stack of errors, pointing at the exact locations you will need to look at, including file names and line numbers, along with the error message.

If you do not see a stack trace of the error, then the error might be handled by a catch clause. The catch clause which is being executed will be the one you need to work at in this case.

Comment: not very helpful, given the stacktrace in the screenshot that only covers framework code. (But then, OP shouldn't post stacktraces *as pictures*)

Comment: @FelixPalmen I would be able to improve my answer if the question is more elaborated, with source-code, for example.